# How to use JsonField instead of many to many field in django

Tags: python, json, django

Let say i have two models like these, and i want to store multiple Book's title in the Author's books.
but i do not want to use ManyToManyField, and i want to use json instead

```
class Book(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Author(models.Model):
      books = JsonField()
```

How can i get the data(title) in the json format from book and store that in Author(books) based on what the user select in django admin panel.(Actually i want to select the books my self, like i do in the many to many field)

Comment: Storing relations in json? not a great idea. You might as well go completely for some NoSQL solution if you want such things. Can you clarify why do you not want to use a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: i don't want to store relations in json. i just want to store the data(book_title)in it.
for the second question i don't want to a thrid party table create.@AbdulAzizBarkat Aziz Barkat

Comment: And _why_ do you want to do that? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Third party table? How is a `ManyToManyField` a third party table? It is a table made in your database itself, it is just a junction table with foreign keys to the 2 related tables (quite normal in SQL). If you consider this as a third party table then I would argue even models are third party tables.

Comment: maybe "thrid party" phrase  wasn't very good here to use , but that Intermediary table we are talking about is not  appropriate for my case to use. @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: can you tell me plz how to get data from one table and store it to another one using json.@AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: As I state above this sounds like an XY problem to me. "not appropriate for my case to use" is not a very great answer to the question of why (just implies the question why is it not appropriate?). All I can do is assume you are trying to make some api and don't really know how to serialize the model data to do this. See [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) if that is the case.